# How to modify constraints right after they are set from storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I need to know how to modify constraints just after they are load from storyboard or nib.

For example in storyboard I put 5 views horizontaly. In code when the view controller loads data the position of this views is based on the data. So is there a metod that I can add to controller? I thought that awakeFromNib will do ther work but it's not. Or maybe I've used it wrong.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was the place: initWithCoder

Or

After the data comes in you can call :

```
 [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

And then you need to implement

```
 - ( void ) updateConstraints
```

But you could also just create all the constraints in code and only add the ones that are needed for the specific data.

What I do is this: ( probably code typos but typed with xCode completion ;) )

```
@interface ...
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL update;
@end

- ( void ) whatever {
    _update = YES;
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- ( void ) updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];

    if( _update ) {
        _update = NO;

       ....CONSTRAINTS...
    }
}
```

Comment: Init with coder is the designated initialisers for views that are created in Storyboard. ( For the guy who deleted his comment )

Comment: The initWithCoder don't work, I already tried it. There is a method layoutSubviews, but this one is called all the time and I need to modified it just the first time.

Comment: You should not use layoutSubviews but use my second way. updateConstraints is made for your problem. Do this it one time just protect it with an if.

Comment: What do you mean with if statement?
So I create a bool something like initialUpdate that will tell me inside updateConstraints method that when this bool is YES it should update otherwise it shouldn't.

Comment: Updated answer @KlemenZagar Because you only want to do the constraints after you got the data ( async? ) and updateConstraints can be called multiple times

Comment: Ok,  this looks like it should work. I'll try it in code later today to check if it works. I'll update answer when I'll try the code.

Comment: @KlemenZagar Was it successful? If so check this answer as the correct one?